# What is the literal meaning of Sallallahu?

Tags: salat, arabic

What is the literal meaning of Sallallahu?

Would it be right if I say 'Allah's salah/salat', which means Allah's blessings, Mercy.

Comment: Salah means either Prayers or Prayers/Blessings. A person can go do Salah, as in go pray. Or a person can say/send Salah as a dua. For example, Muhammad Sala'Lahu Alaihi Wa Salam (Peace/Blessing be upon him) 

"Sallallhu" as you mean is part of "Blessing be upon" - It's 2-words in Arabic.

Answer (score 3):

**Salla** , is derived from **Sila** that means : Connection , link .. etc.

That's why Salah (prayer) is very realted to ***mentioning*** and ***praising***
,

> "surely, I am Allah: There is no god but I: So worship Me , and establish regular prayer for celebrating My praise "

or

> " establish prayer for My remembrance." http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/20:14

[Saheeh International translation]

***Salla Allahu*** , means: may Allah give Salat (or Salawat) .

***Salla*** is a past tense verb , ***Allahu*** : is the subject. (Literally : Allah did Salat.)

It's mentioned usually when saying : May Allah give Salat to his Prophet.  And it means here : mercy and blessings , or means : praising the prophet among the angels.

see : https://islamqa.info/en/69944

https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/97639

https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/36339

Comment: What is the difference between sallalahu and barakallah? Do they both mean mercy?

Comment: @Ahmed you should ask this in a new question how ever this sounds more likely a fit for the [Arabic proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105382/arabic-language?referrer=E7543yclX-MBmqgt1wfCkA2)